# Wrong time in Mailing Report

Tags: civireport, mailing

as said in the title, the mailing report seems to have a wrong time...when I send a mailing to my private email adress at 4 pm and open it right away, the mailing report says I opened it 2 hours ago.
Not much of a big problem here but it triggers me anyway!

Would be very thankful for some help!!

Ben

Comment: Hi Ben,

When you've got things running on different servers, there is a chance that dates and times may be mismatched - e.g. your mail server might be configured with a time zone that is different from the server on which your civi instance is installed and hence the time is incorrectly translated. Determining whether this is the case would be the first step. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Tamar, 
that would make sense. I´ll try to figure it out and let you know if it solved my problem!
Thank you

Comment: Indeed you were right, Tamar!
In the system settings the time was set wrong, now it´s correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad to have been able to help - reposting my comment as a response and kindly requesting that you mark it as accepted given your findings.

> When you've got things running on different servers, there is a chance that dates and times may be mismatched - e.g. your mail server might be configured with a time zone that is different from the server on which your civi instance is installed and hence the time is incorrectly translated. Determining whether this is the case would be the first step.

Glad I could be of help!